# Spring-Boot+jUnit: multiple declaration of @BootstrapWith

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, junit

I'm triing to combine classes dependencies injection & JPA entity use in my jUnit tests.

> My app configuration
>
> - Java 21
> - Built with Maven
> - Spring Boot 2.7
> - jUnit 4.3

All my unit tests runs well with `@SpringBootTest` annotation. But I always need to specify manually all injection with this annotation.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        Tokenizer.class,
        RSSParserService.class,
        HttpClientService.class,
        AutoCompleteService.class,
        DateExtractorService.class
})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AutoCompleteServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private RSSParserService rssService;

    @Test
    public void testRSSWeightingProcess() {

        List<AutoCompleteResult> results = rssService.parseRSSItem(
                "fringilla",
                fields,
                Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofDays(2)));

        assertNotNull(results, "We should have one result");
        assertEquals(1, results.size());
```

**First point is:**
Why must I specify manually all my dependencies ?

Otherwise, I get this kind of error:

```
UnsatisfiedDependency Error creating bean with name 'com.mycompany.api.services.AutoCompleteServiceTest': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rssService';
```

Is there any way to load automatically all my application Spring-Boot context with a global configuration ?

Besides (and that's my **blocking point**): I've just added a test including **JPA entity dependency** (I use a `@Service` classes which use a Repository.)

So I need to use `@DataJpaTest` annotation to load my Repository, because there is no concrete implementation class.

```java
public interface QueryLogRepository extends CrudRepository<QueryLog, Long> {
```

So I've just changed my test class header by

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class AutoCompleteServiceTest {
```

If I let @SprintBootTest annotation, it gives me

```
Found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.mycompany.api.services.AutoCompleteServiceTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper.class)]
```

But If I remove it, it do not find my `@Autowired` services.

I've been looking for alternative, but nothing works.

**What's the good way to manage all dependency injection in jUnit with Spring Boot ?**

Comment: I've tried also `@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)` to initialize spring-boot context. But it also do not find my autowired services.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a global found solution for SpringBoot:

```java
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AutoCompleteServiceTest {
```

All my JPA entities & autowired services work with this